# jQuery dialogs - sharing values between dialogs

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog

My English is bad so I write easily. I'm using Jquery Dialog and I want to show multiple dialogs. (dialog1 opens dialog2 opens dialog 3...)

But the problem is when I open dialog1 and then dialog2 (confirm dialog, So that the user can choose Yes/No in dialog2 and return value to dialog1), I don't know how to return that value until user click the yes or no buttons.

I know Javascript is asynchronous, so when user opens dialog1 and click open dialog2, it won't wait for event in dialog2 to finish.

Here is my source code (simple logic) jsfiddle.net/juRm9/2

Comment: can you share a piece of code ? so that we provide you a jsfiddle.

Comment: Sorry for my bad, this is the first time I've a question in this site. Here is my source code, it is simple logic http://jsfiddle.net/juRm9/2/

Answer (score 1):

all dialogue are nothing but `div`.so store some hidden variable with id inside the div where you want to get the data.

And bind onclick events of second dialogue(according to your requirement onclick of yes or no) to assign the value to hidden element of first div.

Comment: I've tried this idea but I want to call a function which open dialog 2 and return value when user choose yes or no. If do this idea, when open dialog 2 it alway return value without regrad to user's choose in dialog 2.

Comment: so bind the return function onclick of yes/no button of second dialogue.

Comment: I'm newbie with Jquery :). But this is not suitable for my sittuation. Thanks anyway.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/juRm9/2/ please help me with this problem, I want dialog1 will wait response from dialog 2 then it will do some thing

Answer (score 0):

You can use store values in hidden fields, to in the page. then use it any time you want.

Comment: Thanks for your idea, but this is same, because when user open dialog 2, and get hidden value, it alway return it value before user click in yes or no buttons in dialog 2. Really bad for this.